# Can you initialise multiple instances of a class in one single line?

Tags: python, class, initialization, instance

Imagine I would like to compact my code when initialising several instances of a class.

This code works:

```
from ipywidgets import Output,HBox
out1 = Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
out2 = Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
out3 = Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})

with out1: display('here is out1')
with out2: display('here is out2')
with out3: display('here is out3')

display(HBox([out1,out2,out3]))
```

Now what I want is not having to repeat three times the initialization of `out1`, `out2`, and `out3`.

Of course this does not work:

```
out1=out2=out3=Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
```

because those three `out`s are the same object.

Imagine you have like 10 initialisations to do, what is a nice pythonic way to go about it without having to write 10 lines of code?

Other consultations that could not really help me:
[Automatically initialize multiple instance of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59684717/automatically-initialize-multiple-instance-of-class)
[Can one initialize multiple variables of some type in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321901/can-one-initialize-multiple-variables-of-some-type-in-one-line)
[Python creating multiple instances for a single object/class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467604/python-creating-multiple-instances-for-a-single-object-class)

Comment: looping and adding to a list or a dictionary?

Comment: Opinion based, but you should be more interested in code clarity than the number of lines. Have you considered a loop or list comprehension, or a factory constructor function? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: `out1, out2, out3 = [Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'}) for i in range(3)]`?

Comment: I like this answer a lot. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the `Output` objects in a list, and then you can iterate through the list:

```
outputs = [Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'}) for _ in range(3)]

for i, out in enumerate(outputs, 1):
    with out:
        display(f"here is out{i}")

display(HBox(outputs))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind keeping those variables in a list,
I would consider a loop that calls a function

```
from ipywidgets import Output,HBox

def get_obj():
    return Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})

def do_display(out, i):
    with out: display(f"here is out{i}")

outs = [get_obj() for _ in range(3)]
for i, out in enumerate(outs):
    do_display(out, i)
```